# Electron. Autoupdating app when it notices the change in the database or selected server?

Tags: javascript, electron

My client wants applications written in electron which works both offline and online. The application is to connect to the server / database and download data (photos and descriptions of products) so that it can work in the offline version. When it is online, the application checks whether there is any change on the server / database and then an update occurs.

I have already prepared such applications (search engine and product filters with the possibility of generating pdf), but I have no idea how the application would check whether the server existed any of the data and download new photos of products, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah well the question is: Do you want to run you're queries on the Client it self? Because then, if not strictly restricted, someone finds a way to open up the console and sends funny queries.

But anyway... your question:

The easiest way I can think of this, because we don't want to download everything again, is to have a version number for each element.

So the client has one and if that does not match the servers it gets updated. Now you just have to get all IDs. But keep in mid, you still have to handle what happens if an item gets removed or a new one added.

This is not really an answer but I hope it inspired you a little bit.

Oh some after thoughts:

You could get something like a WebSocket between those two. Yes you had to program one more service but

1. The query would be save
2. You could keep track of removed and added items
3. You could work out some timestamp system that you get all items that are newer than the timestamp of the client.. this will be some work though.

nice day, Elias